# How to solve (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1) in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to save the image to my **Download** folder. I already add the permission but I still get the error like below.

I have add the permission in AndroidManifest.xml  like these:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I also have add **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"** in AndroidManifest.xml

Beside that, I also have use the **permission_handler: ^8.1.6** to open the storage permission.

```
 _requestPermission() async {
Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
  Permission.storage,
].request();

final info = statuses[Permission.storage].toString();
print(info);
}
```

Here is the code for download the image. The package I use is **downloads_path_provider: ^0.1.0**

```
 Future<File> downloadImage(Uint8List data, String name) async {
    Directory tempDir = await DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory;
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    var filePath = tempPath + '/$name';

    var bytes = ByteData.view(data.buffer);
    final buffer = bytes.buffer;

    return File(filePath).writeAsBytes(
        buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
  }
```

Here is the error when I want to download the image.

```
E/flutter (26950): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/image-2021-09-23 17:18:47.923358.jpg' 
(OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: Have a look at this Github [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40498)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I already look at this Github but it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how and whats the problem but i added the following lines in the AndroidManafist.xml files and it got fixed.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
```